# How should I find the XPath using selenium webdriver and protractor

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, protractor

I'm a beginner in automation testing. I'm trying to select a value from data list and I got an XPath like mentioned below:

XPath : `html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]`

This is the HTML for the same :

```
<input id="portfolioName" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" ng-model="vm.portfolioName" 
name="portfolioName[]" autocomplete="off" 
list="portfolioNameList" ng-change="vm.onPortfolioNameChange()" onclick="this.value='';" 
style="" type="text"/>
```

When I execute the test case, it displays `No such element found` exception

How do I resolve this problem? I'm using Selenium and protractor.

Comment: You can also open your website, go to developer tools, `right click on element -> copy -> copy xpath`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Avoid the use of '*Absolute XPath*' if possible in your coding.

If your element is having with class, ID, name & Type attributes then try to locate the element with the use of **Relative XPath**.

You can use-

```
XPath: //input[@id='portfolioName']
```

OR

```
XPath: //input[@id='portfolioName'][@type='text']
```

OR

```
Xpath=//input[@type='text' AND @name='portfolioName[]']
```

OR

```
Xpath=//input[contains(@id,'portfolioName')]
```

> Best & easy way to locate Element with ID attribute is **By ID**:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("portfolioName"));
```

Answer (score 4):

An absolute XPath should start with a slash `/`:
`'/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]'`.

It is advised to use relative XPath like: '`//div[@id="portfolioName"]`'. For this to work, the id has to be unique for div tags.

However if the id is unique, you can better identify the object by id and not XPath:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("portfolioName"))
```

Answer (score 4):

**Say "No" to XPaths**, to quote the [Protractor style guide](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/style-guide.md#never-use-xpath):

> - It's the slowest and most brittle locator strategy of all
> - Markup
>     is very easily subject to change and therefore xpath locators require
>     a lot of maintenance
> - xpath expressions are unreadable and very hard
>     to debug

There are better, faster and more readable ways to locate the element:

```
element(by.id("portfolioName"));
element(by.model("vm.portfolioName"));
```

If you are testing an Angular application with Protractor, in theory you should not experience timing issues since Protractor and Angular work together in sync - Angular signals Protractor when it is "ready". But, if you do experience timing issues, you can always add a wait - e.g. waiting for the element to be present:

```
var portfolioName = element(by.id("portfolioName"));
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(portfolioName), 5000);
```

Answer (score 3):

The input element has an id, better use this then the path from the html element to the input element. This path could change as the rendering is in a different state and or as the elements are injected in a different order each time.

Your Xpath could be: `//*[@id="portfolioName"]`

I would also research [CSS selectors](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors) to use instead of Xpath as they are faster, easier to read and more flexible. Learn about [all the other selectors](https://loadfocus.com/blog/2013/09/05/how-to-locate-web-elements-with-selenium-webdriver/) and use XPath as a last resort.